# Is it allowed to create more than 1 drop down menu in Bottom sheet flutter? I am getting an error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

This is my String list:

```
final List<String> cupsize = ['Select', 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large'];

  final List<String> flavour = [
    'Chocolate',
    'Vanilla',
    'Strawberry',
    'Blueberry',
    'Raspberry',
    'Kiwi'
        'Select'
  ];

String _currentCupSize;
String _currentFlavour;
```

And The drop down menu function is as follows:

```
//This is for cupsize

DropdownButtonFormField(
              value: _currentCupSize ?? 'Select',
              items: cupsize.map((size) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: size,
                  child: Text('$size Size'),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
                return _currentCupSize = val;
              }),
            ),

//This is for flavour

DropdownButtonFormField(
              value: _currentFlavour ?? 'One',
              items: flavour.map((flav) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: flav,
                  child: Text('$flav Flavour'),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
                return _currentFlavour = val;
              }),
            ),
```

The cupsize code is working fine but as soon as flavor function is written,
It says:
[image: DropDownMenu Error]

I referred to some other answers but none solved my problem.

Any help will be much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I see here.

One is that you have missed a `,` after `'Kiwi'` in the `List`.

Second, you have `'Select'` in the `flavour` List. But then, your default value for your second `DropdownButtonFormField` is `'One'`.
So either, change the default value to `'Select'` or change the last value in the list to `'One'`;

```
final List<String> flavour = [
  'Chocolate',
  'Vanilla',
  'Strawberry',
  'Blueberry',
  'Raspberry',
  'Kiwi',
  'One'
];
```

Since, it doesn't see your `'One'` default value being in the list, it is throwing the error.